# SQL Reporting Services (SSRS) - Blocked process on ReportServer, SP CheckSessionLock

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, blocking

We frequently see blocking on our SSRS box which houses both front-end Report Manager ReportingService and the SQL database engine with ReportServer & ReportServerTempDB Catalog databases

```
Blocking session:
    Database name: ReportServer
    Application name: Report Server
    Host name: SSRS01
    OS User name: SYSTEM
    Database User name: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
    First 2KB of SQL: CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckSessionLock] @SessionID as varchar(32), @LockVersion  int OUTPUT AS DECLARE @Selected nvarchar(32) SELECT @Selected=SessionID, @LockVersion = LockVersion FROM [ReportServerTempDB].dbo.SessionLock WITH (ROWLOCK) WHERE SessionID = @SessionID

Blocked session:
    Database name: ReportServer
    Application name: Report Server
    Host name: SSRS01
    OS User name: SYSTEM
    Database User name: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
    First 2KB of SQL: CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckSessionLock] @SessionID as varchar(32), @LockVersion  int OUTPUT AS DECLARE @Selected nvarchar(32) SELECT @Selected=SessionID, @LockVersion = LockVersion FROM [ReportServerTempDB].dbo.SessionLock WITH (ROWLOCK) WHERE SessionID = @SessionID
```

Anyone else experience this, and fix it ?